# SQL After Update Trigger confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I hope someone can help me. This is my first post ever, so I hope I explained it well.

I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio.

I am trying to make a trigger that is not letting anyone change the personal number of a person if that person didn't return a computer in a database that I made.

So I am making a trigger for table Person where I have ID_Person primary key, Name, Surname and a Personal_numb.
Also, I made a table called Renting where I have columns: ID_Renting primary key, ID_Person foreign key, ID_Computer foreign key and Date_Rented and Date_Returned columns..
Here is how my code look a like:

```
create trigger NO
On Person
after update
as
 begin
 if update(Personal_numb)
 
 (select ID_Person from Renting
 where Renting.Date_Returned is null)
 begin
 Raiserror('Person needs to return the computer before you try to change their personal number!', 16,1)
 end
 end
```

However, I know that I am missing something between if update(Personal_numb) and select but what is it?

Comment: you need to use `inserted` to obtain the `ID_Person` and then `JOIN` to `Renting` and check for the `Date_Returned`

Comment: Okay, I tried using inserted and deleted, but I don't know how to connect them so it make sense in update trigger.  Can you give me a hint of how to make an update trigger look normal in any other example where I am making it for one table and checking the condition for another?

Comment: Let's take a step backwards. Why do you have this restriction? Do you use this column in other tables (such as dbo.Renting)? Perhaps you simply should not allow this column to be changed at all?

Comment: It's part of an assignment that i was supposed to do and everything else I did right except this part. I know I can make restriction to not allow change it all. This was all just for practice, nothing more than that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
drop trigger if exists trg_Person_upd;
go
create trigger trg_Person_upd on Person
after update
as
set nocount on;

if exists(select * from inserted);
    begin
         if exists (select * 
                    from Renting r
                         join inserted i on r.ID_Person=i.ID_Person
                         join deleted d on r.ID_Person=d.ID_Person
                    where i.Personal_numb<>d.Personal_numb
                          and r.Date_Returned is null))
        throw 50000, 'Person needs to return the computer before you try to change their personal number!', 1;
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

You use `inserted` to join to `renting` and checks for `Date_Rreturned` using `EXISTS()`

Note : I changed the trigger name. Naming it `NO` is rather unusual

```
create trigger TR_Person
On Person
after update
as
begin
    if  update(Personal_numb)
    and exists
        (
            select  *
            from    inserted i  
                    inner join Renting r    on  i.ID    = r.ID_Person
            where   r.Date_Returned     is null
        )
    begin
        Raiserror('Person needs to return the computer before you try to change their personal number!', 16,1)
    end
 end
 go
```

Comment: Okay I got it now. I was just missing 'and exists' part. Thank you so much!

Comment: And also the `inserted`. You need to use `inserted` to determine the rows that is affected by the `update` statement. Please accept the answer that resolve your issue

Comment: Okay, yes. When I was using delete and insert trigger I've been using inserted and deleted, but until now I never used update trigger, so that's why I didn't know where to implement inserted table, but I am good now. Thank you!